# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python

I have a snippet of code which works:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('psftp servername'.split(),stdin=subprocess.PIPE, tdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)   
p.stdin.write('lcd P:\\ORACLE_UNIX\\Development\n')    
p.stdin.write('get //opt//jboss//current//server//default//conf//DMS.properties\n')    
p.stdin.write('bye\n')    
p.stdout.close()    
p.stdin.close()
```

But when I have a variable set (as I will refer to the server in other parts):

```
devserv='servername'  
p = subprocess.Popen('psftp' +devserv.split(),stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p.stdin.write('lcd P:\\ORACLE_UNIX\\Development\n')    
p.stdin.write('get //opt//jboss//current//server//default//conf//DMS.properties\n')    
p.stdin.write('bye\n')    
p.stdout.close()    
p.stdin.close()
```

...I always get *TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects*. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace

`'psftp' +devserv.split()`

with

`('psftp' +devserv).split()`

You need to build the string first and then call `split` on the completed string.

Answer (score 1):

`devserver.split()` returns a list, which is why you're seeing that error - you're trying to concatenate a string with a list.

You could try this instead:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['psftp', devserver], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

[`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is no longer needed since you already have the cmd and args as seperate strings.